# JAVASCRIPT: Replace a single character into a <p>

Tags: dom, replace, character, paragraph

I've got a word in an HTML paragraph. For example 'string':

```
<p id="myWord">string</p>
```

I want to change only a character of that word. For example 'strong':
So I add an html button that calls a function:

```
<button onclick="myFunction">replace 'i'</button>
```

the function in JS is this but it can't access to the fourth character of myWord:

```
function myFunction{
document.getElementById("myWord[3]").innerHTML = 'o';
}
```

Here is the unWorking fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/su3Lrezr/4/

**How can I access to a index of a word in a html paragraph? I already tried to convert myWord into an array with split() method but it doesn't work.**

Thanks everybody

Comment: There is so much wrong with the code here, I don't know where to begin. Start by relearning the syntax for writing and calling functions.

Comment: Yahoo Answer is more helpfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array method:

You'll want to split the string at value 'i' Then rejoin them together with an 'o' in the middle. Then update your *innerHTML*. You will need the *split()* function. This will work:

```
function myFunction(){
      var word = document.getElementById('myWord').innerHTML;
      var result = word.split('i'); 
      var newword = result[0] + "o" + result[1];
      document.getElementById('myWord').innerHTML = newword;
 }
```

Also, as a commenter has mentioned your syntax for calling functions is wrong. You must call functions like this: *myFunction()* and declare them like this: *function myFunction(){ }*